# Binding events handlers for React template rendered on server side

Tags: javascript, reactjs, isomorphic-javascript

In order to get my head around React.js, I'm working on a simple noticeboard app that renders the views on both the client and server side. Unfortunately, I've hit a snag.

The file `components/index.jsx` currently looks like this:

```
var React = require('react');

var Notice = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (
        <div className="noticeitem">
          {this.props.text}
        </div>
    );
  }
});

var NoticeForm = React.createClass({
  handleSubmit: function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('Running');
  },
  render: function () {
    return (
      <form className="noticeForm" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <div className="form-group">
          <textarea className="form-control" placeholder="Your notice..." ref="text" />
        </div>
        <input type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" value="Post" />
      </form>
    );
  }
});

var Index = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    var noticeNodes = this.props.notices.map(function (notice, index) {
      return (
          <Notice key={index} text={notice.text}>
          </Notice>
      );
    });
    return (
        <div>
          <h1>Noticeboard</h1>
          <NoticeForm />
          <div className="noticeList">
            {noticeNodes}
          </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
});

module.exports = Index;
```

It renders fine on the server side, but I note that the `handleSubmit()` method of `NoticeForm` doesn't get bound to the `onSubmit` event, which seems logical. I'm loading the compiled template file when the page loads, so how can I apply this on page load? It's not clear from the documentation how I do so.

The full source code is [here](https://github.com/matthewbdaly/react-noticeboard), although I haven't committed the `handleSubmit()` method yet.

Comment: I have similar problem. Can you please tell me which approached worked for you.

Comment: The answer I accepted worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to re-render your component on the client side. I think what you are doing right now is just taking what you got from the server and dumping it in with something like

```
<div id='view' dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.props.body}} />
```

To get the event handlers to actually bind you should do something like

```
var container = document.getElementById('view');
var component = YOURCOMPONENT HERE
React.renderComponent(component, container);
```

Taking a look at the API doc this will not actually unmount all the domnodes and redraw. It should only attach all the necessary event handlers

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html

> If you call React.render() on a node that already has this
>   server-rendered markup, React will preserve it and only attach event
>   handlers, allowing you to have a very performant first-load
>   experience.

Comment: Hmm... In principle that sounds like it will work. I can't get it to work right now because Index isn't available, and I suspect I'm going to need to use Browserify to get it working, so I'll need to set some time aside to get my head round that, but I'll accept this answer on that basis.